# Функция copy() не хочет копировать в ту же директирию

Tags: php, файлы

В данном коде:

```
copy($dir_big_images.$images_item, $dir_big_images.$images_item)
```

Если брать файл из директории, и в него же копировать его же самого, то не получается.

Получается только копировать из разных директорий.

Почему?

Comment: А какого результата вы хотите добиться, копируя файл сам в себя? Любая файловая система это запретит.

Comment: ну функция же заменяет по-умолчанию  одинаковый файл ..Мне нужно перезаписать его .Как  это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = file_get_contents('путь к файлу');
```

// какие нибудь манипуляции с $content($content .= $content) или что вам там надо

```
file_put_contents('путь к файлу', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php
    mkdir(dirname($dir_big_images), 0777, true);
    copy($dir_big_images.$images_item, $dir_big_images.$images_item);
?>
```

Или просто

```
<?php
    $images_item1 = $images_item2 . '.old';
    copy($images_item1, $images_item2);
?>
```

> "брать файл из директории и в него же копировать его же самого" это не возможно потому что файл уже существует...

Если нужно перезаписать файл используйте **[fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php)**;